# Invalid json variable in succes response

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am trying to send a post data with ajax. But when I receive json response. Error is invalid json variable.
Here is my ajax code.

```
if(flagSubmit == true){
        var postData = $('#frm-dth-recharge').serialize();
        //console.log(postData);
        $('#rechargedth').hide();
        $('#loadingdthgif').css('display','block');
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "<?php echo $this->webroot;?>recharges/processdtherecharge",
            data: postData,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            success: function(recharge_status) {
                //recharge_status = recharge_status.trim();
                var recharge_status = $.parseJSON(recharge_status);
                var  res1 = recharge_status.rechargeStatus;
                var res2 = recharge_status.walletamount;
                if (res1 == "SUCCESS") {
                    msg = "Congratulation, Your recharge has been Done.";
                } else if (res1 == "PENDING") {
                     msg = "Pending, Some technical issue your recharge is in processing.";
                } else if (res1 == "FAILED") {
                     msg = "Sorry, for inconvenient your recharge was not Done.";
                } else {
                     msg = "Sorry, for inconvenient your recharge was not Done.";
                }
                $('#rechargedth').show();
                $('#loadingdthgif').css('display','none');

                $('#frm-dth-recharge').trigger("reset");
                alert(msg);
                $("#dthwallamount").text(res2);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }else{
        return flagSubmit;
    }
}
```

And here is my response Json Variable. I DO not where is I am wrong.
please help.

```
{"STATUS":"PENDING","MOBILE":"30457807","AMOUNT":"50","RPID":"XXXXXX52","AGENTID":"96ea4787d3","OPID

":"","BAL":1149.95,"MSG":"PENDING"}{"rechargeStatus":"SUCCESS","walletamount":"40.5895"}
```

Comment: There is no `Error` property in the response? Also if that's the format the response comes back in, it's not valid JSON.

Comment: Rory McCrossan@please help me  .I am not getting you. can you help me with script .I am new

Comment: Rory McCrossan@but same thing working on  other place

Comment: use `datatype:'json'` in ajax

Comment: Omi @but same code is working on other place .Even  field message is simmilar like this without error. {"STATUS":"FAILED","MOBILE":"30457807","AMOUNT":"10","RPID":"","AGENTID":"ee6661c48b","OPID":"","BAL":0.0,"MSG":"FAILED!! Videocon D2hAmount Between 50.00 To 100000.00"}{"rechargeStatus":"FAILED","walletamount":"40.5895"}

Comment: maybe your json is wrong. it should be like `[{
 "STATUS": "PENDING",
 "MOBILE": "30457807",
 "AMOUNT": "50",
 "RPID": "XXXXXX52",
 "AGENTID": "96ea4787d3",
 "OPID": "",
 "BAL": 1149.95,
 "MSG": "PENDING"
}, {
 "rechargeStatus": "SUCCESS",
 "walletamount": "40.5895"
}]` verify your json.

Comment: verify your json@how can verify

Comment: https://jsonlint.com

Comment: use https://jsonlint.com/ or use the json i have given to you that is already verified

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove bellow line from your ajax method

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
```

and you will be fine.